# I know I am writing this for loop wrong, so how do I write it correctly so that it can accept multiple letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a text to binary converter and it sort of works but it only accepts one letter at a time. How do I make it so it can take multiple letters? Help is greatly appreciated. Also first time posting here so please let me know if I did something wrong.

Before I realized I could just do a for loop I hard coded it for each letter and it was a pain so I just did a loop.

```
letters = {
  'A' : 65,
  'B' : 66,
  'C' : 67,
  'D' : 68,
  'E' : 69,
  'F' : 70,
  'G' : 71,
  'H' : 72,
  'I' : 73,
  'J' : 74,
  'K' : 75,
  'L' : 76,
  'M' : 77,
  'N' : 78,
  'O' : 79,
  'P' : 80,
  'Q' : 81,
  'R' : 82,
  'S ': 83,
  'T' : 84,
  'U' : 85,
  'V' : 86,
  'W' : 87,
  'X' : 88,
  'Y' : 89,
  'Z' : 90,
}
def converter():
    answer = input('What would you like to convert to binary?')
    for i in range(1):
        print(bin(letters.get(answer)))

while True:
    converter()
```

Comment: What do you expect `range(1)` to be?

Comment: `for char in answer: print(bin(letter.get(char)))`

Comment: check out the `ord()` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a string as input and output the binary for each letter in the string

```
def converter():
    answer = input('What would you like to convert to binary?') # Input any char sequence here
    for c in answer:
        print(bin(letters.get(c)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the dictionary, you can use [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) function as below.

```
def converter():
    answer = input('What would you like to convert to binary?')
    for c in answer:
        print(bin(ord(c)))
```

e.g

```
What would you like to convert to binary?A
0b1000001
What would you like to convert to binary?B
0b1000010
What would you like to convert to binary?AB
0b1000001
0b1000010
```

Comment: `ord()` only takes one character so this fails if the input string is longer than 1 Unicode character

Comment: you have to add `bin()` as in question.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. You need another input at the start of your converter() function that says how long it is. So for example, we can add length = int(input()). Then just input the string to convert like you already did. Also you can make your binary print so much easier if you use ord() whit a character in it, so you don't need the letters dictionary at all.So this is your new converter() function:

```
def converter():
    length = int(input("lenght of the letters"))
    letters = input("what letters do you want to turn in binary?")
    for i in range(length):
        print(bin(ord(letters[i]), ' ')) # ' ' for the spacing between the values
```

That is it. I will now explain the solution:

first we prompt the user whit the characters that he wants to turn into binary.
Now we, as we have the length we go through it whit a for loop.

If you don't know what letters[i] does, it gets the i-th index of the string. Index is just a way to number down elements of a list,string,tuples and possibly more datatypes. Note that they start from 0 and end whit n-1, if n is the length of the string/list/tuple. Also note that they cant be used in dictionaries --> you can use dictionary[i], but the "i" is not a index, it is a key. Okay, now that we got that covered (if you didn't know it already) lets that back to the code. So the range function if it has only one argument it starts from 0. So that is why the index works. And finally the print. ord() function gets the binary of a character(this is a string but whit a length of 1 in python). So letters[i] gets the i-th element of the string which is only a character so the ord() function works. Also you can see the alternative solutions here(but i wont explain them because i am tired of typing):
solution #2:

```
def converter():
    #length = int(input("lenght of the letters"))
    letters = input("what letters do you want to turn in binary?")
    for i in range(len(letters)): # len() gets the lenght of letters
        print(bin(ord(letters[i]), ' ')) # ' ' for the spacing between the values
```

Solution #3:

```
def converter():
    #length = int(input("length of the letters"))
    letters = input("what letters do you want to turn in binary?")
    for i in letters:
        print(bin(ord(letters[i]), ' ')) # ' ' for the spacing between the values
```

Here it is. Bye!!

Comment: thank you for the response! sorry but I had already figured it out cheers though!